# c++ why new an array of class with destructor will need another 8 bytes to store the number of objects?

Tags: c++

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
    int t = -1;
public:
    ~A() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A[4];
    return 0;
}
```

in VS2022 When I add a breakpoint just before `return` then run, and look at the memory address pointed by `a`, it appends 8 more bytes before to store the value `4`.

What are the advantages of using this additional `8 bytes` to keep track of the number of objects? Even without this extra `8 bytes`, the compiler still knows the total size of the class array and can calculate totalsize/sizeof(A) to determine the number of instances of class A in all cases, thus saving 8 bytes permanently. Are there any concerns regarding memory alignment or trade-offs between speed and space that make this `8 bytes` indispensable?

Comment: Now add a `delete [] a` statement and see what it does.

Comment: Probably because the compiler need to know how many objects there are, so `delete[]` knows how many objects to destruct.

Comment: And with that said, please don't use `new[]` and `delete[]`. Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to expand a little bit on the comments:

If `A` has no destructor (either explicit or implicit), then `delete [] a` can just free the storage allocated for the array of `A`s that make up `a`.  It doesn't need to know how many `A`s you allocated, because it doesn't need to work its way through them to call their destructors.  It just needs to free the storage needed for 4 `A`s, and, behind the scenes, that's likely to be a simple call to `free`.

However, once you add a destructor, the equation changes.  Pseudo code for `delete [] a` then becomes:

```
for each A
    destroy A
free the array of As
```

and to do that, the compiler needs to know how many `A`s you allocated (which it stores at the start of the memory block, hence those extra 8 bytes).

And what do I mean by an implicit destructor?  (I invented that term, there's probably a more official one).  Well, suppose `A` were to look like this:

```
class A {
    std::string s;
};
```

*Now*, when an `A` must be destroyed, `s` must be destroyed too (because it has a destructor of its own, which also needs to be called).  So, `A` *does* have a destructor, even though you haven't defined one.  The compiler did that for you, and it's essential that `delete [] a` calls them all.

Too many `A`s already.

**Edit:**

Alex asks in the comments (and I think this is a good question): "But if without this 8 more bytes the compiler still knows the total size of the class array, why doesn't it just calculate `totalsize` / `sizeof(A)` to get the number of `A`s?"

Well, thing is, there's no reliable way, in the general case, to get `totalsize` from that array of `A`s.  There are things like `malloc_size`, but they're platform specific and don't promise to return the exact size requested by the call to `new []`.  So the compiler plays it safe and adds those extra 8 bytes to make sure that things don't break.

Oh, so how does `free` work?  Well, `malloc` and `free` store some extra housekeeping data before the allocated block to keep track.  But the block might actually be bigger than the size requested by the call to `new []` (and usually is), so adding an API call to return the size requested would bloat said housekeeping data, which is probably not what most people want.

Comment: But if without this 8 more bytes the compiler still knows the total size of the `class array`, why doesn't it just calculate `totalsize/sizeof(A)` to get the number of `A`s in all cases so it doesn't need this 8 bytes forever? Are there some concerns about memory alignment of `speed space trade-off` in it?

Comment: @AlexRoddick Because something declared as `A*` doesn't need to contain `A` objects only. If you have `class B:public A {float u;};`, then `A* a = new B[4]` is perfectly valid and `totalsize/sizeof(A)` wouldn't return anything useful (that is all assuming `~A()` is `virtual`, otherwise trying to `delete[] a` would be UB).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `A *a = new B[4];` might be valid alone, but `a` is not pointing to an array of `B`s nor to an array of `A`s. `a[0]` is the `A` subobject of the first `B`. `a[1]` refers to no object at all; it is undefined behavior to read it. `delete[] a` is also undefined behavior (even if `~A()` is `virtual`). `delete[]` doesn't have to deal with the case that you give it a pointer to a subclass of the static type, because that's undefined behavior. Think about it! If `struct A { float x; }; struct B : A { float y; }; B *b = new B[2]; A *a = b;`, then `a[1].x` is probably `b[0].y`!

Comment: @AlexRoddick You say the compiler should take into account the `totalsize`. But how will the compiler know the `totalsize` if it haven't stored it somewhere?

Comment: @heapunderrun My fault.. I have mixed up `operator new[]` and `new[]`..

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This is not the reason. Your scenario is not legal in C++ (or [please find the bug here](https://godbolt.org/z/fx3WqMErv)).

Comment: @alex Answered the question in your first comment by editing my answer.  It's good to be curious, I like it.  Don't understand your last comment.

Comment: "why doesn't it just calculate totalsize/sizeof(A)" There are several reasons. **One**, `totalsize` need not be stored anywhere. An implementation need not allocate exactly the number of bytes requested. It can always round up the size to the nearest power of 2 for example. **Two**, the number of constructed elements is not always the requested number of elements. What happens if an exception is thrown in the middle of array elements construction?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Ah yes, exceptions.  Forgot about that, thanks.  Tricky little devils.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Hmmm, thought about this some more.  If an exception is thrown constructing, say `A [2]`, after the constructor has unwound we just need to destroy `A [1]` and then `A [0]`, which we can do by simply walking backwards through the array until we get to the beginning.  So, unless I'm mistaken (bet I am), the count isn't needed for that.  Cheers.

Comment: @PaulSanders You are right, the counter could be held in a register or on the stack.